# How to Split a Sql Server Table in Multiple tables which have some data?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has 350 columns and around 10000 rows. Now I need to break it into multiple tables and also manage data across all the tables with accuracy.

Comment: Please refer to post for vertical partitioning concept. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302773/what-are-horizontal-and-vertical-partitions-in-database-and-what-is-the-differen

Comment: Is there anything stopping you to do the above task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are horizontal and vertical partitions in database and what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302773/what-are-horizontal-and-vertical-partitions-in-database-and-what-is-the-differen)